# Reference a variable with require or re-evaluate

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native

In my react-native app, the styles folder has following structure.

```
-styles
|- StyleA.js
|- StyleB.js
```

In StyleA.js, i have following exports:

```
const containerWidth = Math.min(300, DeviceWidth / 2)
module.exports = {
  scoreCard : {
    width : containerWidth,
    backgroundColor: 'grey'
  },
  container : {
    width : containerWidth,
    padding : 10
  }
}
```

In StyleB.js, i have following exports:

```
module.exports = {
  forumView : {
    width : Math.min(300, DeviceWidth / 2), // or let style = require('./StyleA.js') && use style.scoreCard.width
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    paddingVertical: 15,
    borderRadius : 5
  }
}
```

Here, in StyleB.js, i wanted to use the same value declared in StyleA.js in containerWidth, i see 3 options:

1. Declare containerWidth global to be used across both files.
2. Compute `Math.min(300, DeviceWidth / 2)` again for the width in StyleB.js
3. Declare `let style = require('StyleA.js')` in StyleB.js and reference `style.scoreCard.width`

I feel like option 1 would probably be more suitable for this kind of situation. I am assuming interms of the cost of computing `Math.min()` and evaluating the reference by declaring `require('StyleA.js')` wont have much advantage to offer one over the other. Any thoughts?

Comment: I would go with the first approach.  in the second approach you are duplicating logic.  In the 3rd approach you introduce the risk that a future editor of StyleA.js changes that value without realizing it will impact StyleB.js.

Comment: 1st and 2nd options are fine. If you don't want to use `Math.min()`, you can try: `width: DeviceWidth / 2 > 300 ? 300 : DeviceWidth / 2`. In case you're worrying about performance, I can tell you that: both JS thread and Native thread are blazing fast, and the only bottleneck here is the bridge.